# How to use nested filters to detect if there is only one li & that its child is only <strong>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to apply a class to `<ul>` only if it has a single `<li>` that contains only one single child which should be `<strong>` & nothing else (no text node or other elements before or after the `<strong>`.

I have referred to multiple posts here that solve different parts of the problem above. And I have written the following code. However, it is adding the class to all `<ul>` & the filtering condition is not getting applied.

```
$('ul.list-style').filter(function(){   
                return $(this).children("li")
                              .filter(function(){ return $(this).contents()
                                          .filter(function() { return this.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE || (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && !!$.trim(this.nodeValue)) }).length=1 })
                              .filter(function(){ return $(this).children("strong").length = 1 }).length = 1 })
                .addClass("only-strong");
```

Comment: `no text or tags after strong` can there be text or tags within the `<li>` before `<strong>` ... e.g. `<li>This is <strong>OK</strong></li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative - single filter - I believe it works

```js
$('ul.list-style > li:only-child > strong:only-child').filter(function() {
  return !this.nextSibling;
}).parent().parent('ul.list-style').addClass('only-strong');
```

```css
.only-strong {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='list-style'>
  <li><strong>Must be RED</strong></li>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='list-style'>
  <li>Also must be <strong>RED</strong></li>
</ul>
<ul class='list-style'>
  <li>Can't be <strong>Red</strong> with text outside of strong</li>
</ul>
<ul class='list-style'>
  <li><strong>Should not be red</strong></li>
  <li>has two li's</li>
</ul>
<ul class='list-style'>
  <li><strong>Not red</strong> something after strong</li>
  <li><strong>and has two li's</strong></li>
</ul>
<ul class='list-style'>
  <li><strong>NOT RED </strong><span>there's a span here</span></li>
</ul>
```

a note about

```
return !this.nextSibling;
```

That means `strong` is the last node in `li` but you can have text nodes before it ... if it needs to be the **ONLY** node in `li`

```
return !(this.nextSibling || this.previousSibling);
```

or even

```
return this.nextSibling === this.previousSibling;
```

since that's only ever true if both are `null`

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as you're expecting, just replace `=` with `==` in every filter `return`:

```js
$('ul.list-style').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children("li")
      .filter(function() {
        return $(this).contents()
          .filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE || (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && !!$.trim(this.nodeValue))
          }).length == 1
      })
      .filter(function() {
        return $(this).children("strong").length == 1
      }).length == 1
  })
  .addClass("only-strong");
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.only-strong {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-style">
  <li><strong>strong</strong></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-style">
  <li>f</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-style">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this fails if for `<ul class='list-style'>
  <li><strong>Should not be blue</strong></li>
  <li>because two li's</li>
</ul>`

Comment: yep, I just wanted to correct OP's code for as to why it wasn't working

Comment: Fair enough then

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code as an alternative to your code -

```js
$('ul.list-style').filter(function() {
    if($(this).children('li').length ==1) {
       var hasStrongElementOnly = false;
       var $children = $(this).children('li').children();
       if($children.length > 0 ) {
         hasStrongElementOnly = true;
       }
       $(this).children('li').children().each(function(){
           if(!$(this).is('strong')) {
              hasStrongElementOnly = false;
           }
       });
       
       if(hasStrongElementOnly) {
         return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
   
  })
  .addClass("only-strong");
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.only-strong {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-style">
  <li><strong>strong</strong> oops fail</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-style">
  <li>f</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-style">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
</ul>
```